# how to count word frequency of words in dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary like below:

```
[{'mississippi': 1, 'worth': 1, 'reading': 1}, {'commonplace': 1, 'river': 1, 'contrary': 1, 'ways': 1, 'remarkable': 1}, {'considering': 1, 'missouri': 1, 'main': 1, 'branch': 1, 'longest': 1, 'river': 1, 'world--four': 1}, {'seems': 1, 'safe': 1, 'crookedest': 1, 'river': 1, 'part': 1, 'journey': 1, 'uses': 1, 'cover': 1, 'ground': 1, 'crow': 1, 'fly': 1, 'six': 1, 'seventy-five': 1}, {'discharges': 1, 'water': 1, 'st': 1}, {'lawrence': 1, 'twenty-five': 1, 'rhine': 1, 'thirty-eight': 1, 'thames': 1}, {'river': 1, 'vast': 1, 'drainage-basin:': 1, 'draws': 1, 'water': 1, 'supply': 1, 'twenty-eight': 1, 'states': 1, 'territories': 1, 'delaware': 1, 'atlantic': 1, 'seaboard': 1, 'country': 1, 'idaho': 1, 'pacific': 1, 'slope--a': 1, 'spread': 1, 'forty-five': 1, 'degrees': 1, 'longitude': 1}, {'mississippi': 1, 'receives': 1, 'carries': 1, 'gulf': 1, 'water': 1, 'fifty-four': 1, 'subordinate': 1, 'rivers': 1, 'navigable': 1, 'steamboats': 1, 'hundreds': 1, 'flats': 1, 'keels': 1}, {'area': 1, 'drainage-basin': 1, 'combined': 1, 'areas': 1, 'england': 1, 'wales': 1, 'scotland': 1, 'ireland': 1, 'france': 1, 'spain': 1, 'portugal': 1, 'germany': 1, 'austria': 1, 'italy': 1, 'turkey': 1, 'almost': 1, 'wide': 1, 'region': 1, 'fertile': 1, 'mississippi': 1, 'valley': 1, 'proper': 1, 'exceptionally': 1}]
```

And I want to change it to my desired output like below to calculate score of similarity between two target words:

```
river 4
    ground: 1
    journey: 1
    longitude: 1
    main: 1
    world--four: 1
    contrary: 1
    cover: 1
    delaware: 1
    remarkable: 1
    vast: 1
    forty-five: 1
    crookedest: 1
    territories: 1
    spread: 1
    country: 1
    longest: 1
    fly: 1
    atlantic: 1
    crow: 1
    supply: 1
    seems: 1
    idaho: 1
    seaboard: 1
    states: 1
    ways: 1
    degrees: 1
    part: 1
    twenty-eight: 1
    pacific: 1
    branch: 1
    water: 1
    considering: 1
    six: 1
    safe: 1
    commonplace: 1
    draws: 1
    drainage-basin: 1
    uses: 1
    seventy-five: 1
    slope--a: 1
    missouri: 1
mississippi 3
    area: 1
    steamboats: 1
    germany: 1
    reading: 1
    france: 1
    proper: 1
    fifty-four: 1
    turkey: 1
    exceptionally: 1
    areas: 1
    carries: 1
    combined: 1
    flats: 1
    receives: 1
    england: 1
    italy: 1
    scotland: 1
    wales: 1
    almost: 1
    navigable: 1
    austria: 1
    region: 1
    wide: 1
    spain: 1
    subordinate: 1
    drainage-basin: 1
    hundreds: 1
    keels: 1
    portugal: 1
    water: 1
    gulf: 1
    ireland: 1
    rivers: 1
    valley: 1
    fertile: 1
    worth: 1
water 3
    steamboats: 1
    spread: 1
    country: 1
    states: 1
    longitude: 1
    fifty-four: 1
    pacific: 1
    vast: 1
    subordinate: 1
    carries: 1
    keels: 1
    flats: 1
    supply: 1
    receives: 1
    atlantic: 1
    forty-five: 1
    river: 1
    rivers: 1
    idaho: 1
    mississippi: 1
    seaboard: 1
    navigable: 1
    discharges: 1
    degrees: 1
    twenty-eight: 1
    drainage-basin: 1
    hundreds: 1
    st: 1
    gulf: 1
    draws: 1
    delaware: 1
    territories: 1
    slope--a: 1
drainage-basin 2
    area: 1
    spread: 1
    country: 1
    states: 1
    mississippi: 1
    longitude: 1
    france: 1
    proper: 1
    vast: 1
    turkey: 1
    forty-five: 1
    areas: 1
    combined: 1
    germany: 1
    exceptionally: 1
    valley: 1
    supply: 1
    fertile: 1
    atlantic: 1
    italy: 1
    river: 1
    idaho: 1
    wales: 1
    almost: 1
    seaboard: 1
    spain: 1
    austria: 1
    region: 1
    degrees: 1
    twenty-eight: 1
    wide: 1
    england: 1
    portugal: 1
    water: 1
    ireland: 1
    pacific: 1
    draws: 1
    delaware: 1
    territories: 1
    scotland: 1
    slope--a: 1
area 1
    germany: 1
    austria: 1
    mississippi: 1
    france: 1
    proper: 1
    england: 1
    turkey: 1
    exceptionally: 1
    areas: 1
    combined: 1
    scotland: 1
    italy: 1
    spain: 1
    wales: 1
    almost: 1
    fertile: 1
    region: 1
    wide: 1
    drainage-basin: 1
    portugal: 1
    ireland: 1
    valley: 1
journey 1
    ground: 1
    seems: 1
    part: 1
    cover: 1
    crow: 1
    crookedest: 1
    six: 1
    safe: 1
    uses: 1
    seventy-five: 1
    river: 1
    fly: 1
seems 1
    ground: 1
    journey: 1
    part: 1
    cover: 1
    crow: 1
    crookedest: 1
    six: 1
    safe: 1
    uses: 1
    seventy-five: 1
    river: 1
    fly: 1
states 1
    spread: 1
    country: 1
    degrees: 1
    longitude: 1
    twenty-eight: 1
    drainage-basin: 1
    vast: 1
    forty-five: 1
    water: 1
    seaboard: 1
    pacific: 1
    draws: 1
    delaware: 1
    territories: 1
    atlantic: 1
    supply: 1
    slope--a: 1
    river: 1
    idaho: 1
slope--a 1
    spread: 1
    country: 1
    states: 1
    degrees: 1
    longitude: 1
    drainage-basin: 1
    vast: 1
    forty-five: 1
    water: 1
    seaboard: 1
    pacific: 1
    draws: 1
    delaware: 1
    territories: 1
    atlantic: 1
    supply: 1
    twenty-eight: 1
    river: 1
    idaho: 1
remarkable 1
    contrary: 1
    river: 1
    commonplace: 1
    ways: 1
vast 1
    spread: 1
    country: 1
    states: 1
    degrees: 1
    longitude: 1
    twenty-eight: 1
    drainage-basin: 1
    pacific: 1
    forty-five: 1
    water: 1
    seaboard: 1
    draws: 1
    delaware: 1
    territories: 1
    atlantic: 1
    supply: 1
    slope--a: 1
    river: 1
    idaho: 1
forty-five 1
    spread: 1
    longitude: 1
    country: 1
    states: 1
    degrees: 1
    slope--a: 1
    drainage-basin: 1
    vast: 1
    pacific: 1
    water: 1
    seaboard: 1
    draws: 1
    delaware: 1
    territories: 1
    atlantic: 1
    supply: 1
    twenty-eight: 1
    river: 1
    idaho: 1
crookedest 1
    ground: 1
    journey: 1
    seems: 1
    part: 1
    cover: 1
    crow: 1
    six: 1
    safe: 1
    uses: 1
    seventy-five: 1
    river: 1
    fly: 1
carries 1
    mississippi: 1
    steamboats: 1
    navigable: 1
    fifty-four: 1
    keels: 1
    hundreds: 1
    subordinate: 1
    water: 1
    gulf: 1
    flats: 1
    rivers: 1
    receives: 1
germany 1
    area: 1
    austria: 1
    mississippi: 1
    france: 1
    proper: 1
    exceptionally: 1
    turkey: 1
    england: 1
    areas: 1
    combined: 1
    scotland: 1
    italy: 1
    spain: 1
    wales: 1
    almost: 1
    fertile: 1
    region: 1
    wide: 1
    drainage-basin: 1
    portugal: 1
    ireland: 1
    valley: 1
longest 1
    main: 1
    river: 1
    world--four: 1
    branch: 1
    missouri: 1
    considering: 1
flats 1
    mississippi: 1
    steamboats: 1
    navigable: 1
    carries: 1
    fifty-four: 1
    keels: 1
    hundreds: 1
    subordinate: 1
    water: 1
    gulf: 1
    rivers: 1
    receives: 1
supply 1
    spread: 1
    longitude: 1
    country: 1
    states: 1
    degrees: 1
    slope--a: 1
    drainage-basin: 1
    vast: 1
    forty-five: 1
    water: 1
    seaboard: 1
    pacific: 1
    draws: 1
    delaware: 1
    territories: 1
    atlantic: 1
    twenty-eight: 1
    river: 1
    idaho: 1
receives 1
    mississippi: 1
    steamboats: 1
    navigable: 1
    carries: 1
    fifty-four: 1
    keels: 1
    hundreds: 1
    subordinate: 1
    water: 1
    gulf: 1
    flats: 1
    rivers: 1
crow 1
    ground: 1
    journey: 1
    seems: 1
    part: 1
    cover: 1
    crookedest: 1
    six: 1
    safe: 1
    uses: 1
    seventy-five: 1
    river: 1
    fly: 1
scotland 1
    area: 1
    germany: 1
    austria: 1
    mississippi: 1
    france: 1
    proper: 1
    exceptionally: 1
    turkey: 1
    england: 1
    areas: 1
    combined: 1
    spain: 1
    italy: 1
    wales: 1
    almost: 1
    fertile: 1
    region: 1
    wide: 1
    drainage-basin: 1
    portugal: 1
    ireland: 1
    valley: 1
country 1
    spread: 1
    idaho: 1
    states: 1
    degrees: 1
    longitude: 1
    twenty-eight: 1
    drainage-basin: 1
    vast: 1
    forty-five: 1
    water: 1
    seaboard: 1
    pacific: 1
    draws: 1
    delaware: 1
    territories: 1
    atlantic: 1
    supply: 1
    slope--a: 1
    river: 1
thames 1
    thirty-eight: 1
    rhine: 1
    lawrence: 1
    twenty-five: 1
england 1
    area: 1
    germany: 1
    austria: 1
    mississippi: 1
    france: 1
    proper: 1
    exceptionally: 1
    turkey: 1
    region: 1
    areas: 1
    combined: 1
    scotland: 1
    italy: 1
    spain: 1
    wales: 1
    almost: 1
    fertile: 1
    wide: 1
    drainage-basin: 1
    portugal: 1
    ireland: 1
    valley: 1
navigable 1
    mississippi: 1
    steamboats: 1
    carries: 1
    fifty-four: 1
    keels: 1
    hundreds: 1
    subordinate: 1
    water: 1
    gulf: 1
    flats: 1
    rivers: 1
    receives: 1
austria 1
    area: 1
    germany: 1
    mississippi: 1
    france: 1
    proper: 1
    region: 1
    turkey: 1
    england: 1
    areas: 1
    combined: 1
    exceptionally: 1
    scotland: 1
    italy: 1
    spain: 1
    wales: 1
    almost: 1
    fertile: 1
    wide: 1
    drainage-basin: 1
    portugal: 1
    ireland: 1
    valley: 1
rhine 1
    thirty-eight: 1
    thames: 1
    lawrence: 1
    twenty-five: 1
part 1
    ground: 1
    journey: 1
    seems: 1
    cover: 1
    crow: 1
    crookedest: 1
    six: 1
    safe: 1
    uses: 1
    seventy-five: 1
    river: 1
    fly: 1
twenty-eight 1
    spread: 1
    country: 1
    states: 1
    degrees: 1
    longitude: 1
    drainage-basin: 1
    vast: 1
    forty-five: 1
    water: 1
    seaboard: 1
    pacific: 1
    draws: 1
    delaware: 1
    territories: 1
    atlantic: 1
    supply: 1
    slope--a: 1
    river: 1
    idaho: 1
branch 1
    main: 1
    longest: 1
    river: 1
    world--four: 1
    missouri: 1
    considering: 1
hundreds 1
    mississippi: 1
    steamboats: 1
    navigable: 1
    carries: 1
    fifty-four: 1
    keels: 1
    subordinate: 1
    water: 1
    gulf: 1
    flats: 1
    rivers: 1
    receives: 1
st 1
    water: 1
    discharges: 1
considering 1
    main: 1
    longest: 1
    river: 1
    world--four: 1
    branch: 1
    missouri: 1
six 1
    ground: 1
    journey: 1
    seems: 1
    part: 1
    cover: 1
    crow: 1
    crookedest: 1
    fly: 1
    safe: 1
    uses: 1
    seventy-five: 1
    river: 1
gulf 1
    mississippi: 1
    steamboats: 1
    navigable: 1
    carries: 1
    fifty-four: 1
    keels: 1
    hundreds: 1
    subordinate: 1
    water: 1
    flats: 1
    rivers: 1
    receives: 1
ireland 1
    area: 1
    germany: 1
    austria: 1
    mississippi: 1
    france: 1
    proper: 1
    exceptionally: 1
    turkey: 1
    england: 1
    areas: 1
    combined: 1
    scotland: 1
    italy: 1
    spain: 1
    wales: 1
    almost: 1
    fertile: 1
    region: 1
    wide: 1
    drainage-basin: 1
    portugal: 1
    valley: 1
safe 1
    ground: 1
    journey: 1
    seems: 1
    part: 1
    cover: 1
    crow: 1
    crookedest: 1
    six: 1
    uses: 1
    seventy-five: 1
    river: 1
    fly: 1
commonplace 1
    contrary: 1
    river: 1
    remarkable: 1
    ways: 1
draws 1
    spread: 1
    longitude: 1
    country: 1
    states: 1
    degrees: 1
    slope--a: 1
    drainage-basin: 1
    vast: 1
    forty-five: 1
    water: 1
    seaboard: 1
    pacific: 1
    supply: 1
    delaware: 1
    territories: 1
    atlantic: 1
    twenty-eight: 1
    river: 1
    idaho: 1
delaware 1
    spread: 1
    longitude: 1
    country: 1
    states: 1
    degrees: 1
    slope--a: 1
    drainage-basin: 1
    vast: 1
    forty-five: 1
    water: 1
    seaboard: 1
    pacific: 1
    draws: 1
    territories: 1
    atlantic: 1
    supply: 1
    twenty-eight: 1
    river: 1
    idaho: 1
thirty-eight 1
    thames: 1
    rhine: 1
    lawrence: 1
    twenty-five: 1
longitude 1
    spread: 1
    country: 1
    states: 1
    degrees: 1
    slope--a: 1
    drainage-basin: 1
    vast: 1
    forty-five: 1
    water: 1
    seaboard: 1
    pacific: 1
    draws: 1
    delaware: 1
    territories: 1
    atlantic: 1
    supply: 1
    twenty-eight: 1
    river: 1
    idaho: 1
world--four 1
    main: 1
    longest: 1
    river: 1
    branch: 1
    missouri: 1
    considering: 1
lawrence 1
    thirty-eight: 1
    thames: 1
    rhine: 1
    twenty-five: 1
ground 1
    journey: 1
    seems: 1
    part: 1
    cover: 1
    crow: 1
    crookedest: 1
    six: 1
    safe: 1
    uses: 1
    seventy-five: 1
    river: 1
    fly: 1
steamboats 1
    mississippi: 1
    navigable: 1
    carries: 1
    fifty-four: 1
    keels: 1
    hundreds: 1
    subordinate: 1
    water: 1
    gulf: 1
    flats: 1
    rivers: 1
    receives: 1
spread 1
    seaboard: 1
    country: 1
    states: 1
    degrees: 1
    longitude: 1
    twenty-eight: 1
    drainage-basin: 1
    vast: 1
    forty-five: 1
    water: 1
    pacific: 1
    draws: 1
    delaware: 1
    territories: 1
    atlantic: 1
    supply: 1
    slope--a: 1
    river: 1
    idaho: 1
idaho 1
    spread: 1
    country: 1
    states: 1
    degrees: 1
    longitude: 1
    twenty-eight: 1
    drainage-basin: 1
    vast: 1
    forty-five: 1
    water: 1
    seaboard: 1
    pacific: 1
    draws: 1
    delaware: 1
    territories: 1
    atlantic: 1
    supply: 1
    slope--a: 1
    river: 1
reading 1
    mississippi: 1
    worth: 1
almost 1
    area: 1
    germany: 1
    austria: 1
    france: 1
    proper: 1
    england: 1
    turkey: 1
    exceptionally: 1
    areas: 1
    combined: 1
    scotland: 1
    italy: 1
    spain: 1
    wales: 1
    mississippi: 1
    fertile: 1
    region: 1
    wide: 1
    drainage-basin: 1
    portugal: 1
    ireland: 1
    valley: 1
contrary 1
    river: 1
    remarkable: 1
    commonplace: 1
    ways: 1
cover 1
    ground: 1
    journey: 1
    seems: 1
    part: 1
    crow: 1
    crookedest: 1
    six: 1
    safe: 1
    uses: 1
    seventy-five: 1
    river: 1
    fly: 1
france 1
    area: 1
    germany: 1
    austria: 1
    mississippi: 1
    proper: 1
    england: 1
    turkey: 1
    exceptionally: 1
    areas: 1
    combined: 1
    scotland: 1
    italy: 1
    spain: 1
    wales: 1
    almost: 1
    fertile: 1
    region: 1
    wide: 1
    drainage-basin: 1
    portugal: 1
    ireland: 1
    valley: 1
spain 1
    area: 1
    germany: 1
    austria: 1
    mississippi: 1
    france: 1
    proper: 1
    exceptionally: 1
    turkey: 1
    england: 1
    areas: 1
    combined: 1
    scotland: 1
    italy: 1
    wales: 1
    almost: 1
    fertile: 1
    region: 1
    wide: 1
    drainage-basin: 1
    portugal: 1
    ireland: 1
    valley: 1
pacific 1
    spread: 1
    longitude: 1
    country: 1
    states: 1
    degrees: 1
    slope--a: 1
    drainage-basin: 1
    vast: 1
    forty-five: 1
    water: 1
    seaboard: 1
    draws: 1
    delaware: 1
    territories: 1
    atlantic: 1
    supply: 1
    twenty-eight: 1
    river: 1
    idaho: 1
turkey 1
    area: 1
    germany: 1
    austria: 1
    mississippi: 1
    france: 1
    proper: 1
    exceptionally: 1
    england: 1
    areas: 1
    combined: 1
    scotland: 1
    italy: 1
    spain: 1
    wales: 1
    almost: 1
    fertile: 1
    region: 1
    wide: 1
    drainage-basin: 1
    portugal: 1
    ireland: 1
    valley: 1
fifty-four 1
    mississippi: 1
    steamboats: 1
    navigable: 1
    carries: 1
    hundreds: 1
    keels: 1
    subordinate: 1
    water: 1
    gulf: 1
    flats: 1
    rivers: 1
    receives: 1
subordinate 1
    mississippi: 1
    steamboats: 1
    navigable: 1
    carries: 1
    fifty-four: 1
    keels: 1
    hundreds: 1
    water: 1
    gulf: 1
    flats: 1
    rivers: 1
    receives: 1
territories 1
    spread: 1
    idaho: 1
    states: 1
    degrees: 1
    longitude: 1
    twenty-eight: 1
    drainage-basin: 1
    vast: 1
    forty-five: 1
    water: 1
    seaboard: 1
    pacific: 1
    draws: 1
    delaware: 1
    supply: 1
    atlantic: 1
    slope--a: 1
    river: 1
    country: 1
combined 1
    area: 1
    germany: 1
    austria: 1
    mississippi: 1
    france: 1
    proper: 1
    exceptionally: 1
    turkey: 1
    england: 1
    areas: 1
    scotland: 1
    italy: 1
    spain: 1
    wales: 1
    almost: 1
    fertile: 1
    region: 1
    wide: 1
    drainage-basin: 1
    portugal: 1
    ireland: 1
    valley: 1
exceptionally 1
    area: 1
    germany: 1
    austria: 1
    mississippi: 1
    france: 1
    proper: 1
    england: 1
    turkey: 1
    region: 1
    areas: 1
    combined: 1
    scotland: 1
    italy: 1
    spain: 1
    wales: 1
    almost: 1
    fertile: 1
    wide: 1
    drainage-basin: 1
    portugal: 1
    ireland: 1
    valley: 1
region 1
    area: 1
    germany: 1
    austria: 1
    mississippi: 1
    france: 1
    proper: 1
    exceptionally: 1
    turkey: 1
    england: 1
    areas: 1
    combined: 1
    scotland: 1
    italy: 1
    spain: 1
    wales: 1
    almost: 1
    fertile: 1
    wide: 1
    drainage-basin: 1
    portugal: 1
    ireland: 1
    valley: 1
twenty-five 1
    thirty-eight: 1
    thames: 1
    lawrence: 1
    rhine: 1
rivers 1
    mississippi: 1
    steamboats: 1
    navigable: 1
    carries: 1
    fifty-four: 1
    keels: 1
    hundreds: 1
    subordinate: 1
    water: 1
    gulf: 1
    flats: 1
    receives: 1
fly 1
    ground: 1
    journey: 1
    seems: 1
    part: 1
    cover: 1
    crow: 1
    crookedest: 1
    six: 1
    safe: 1
    uses: 1
    seventy-five: 1
    river: 1
atlantic 1
    spread: 1
    longitude: 1
    country: 1
    states: 1
    degrees: 1
    slope--a: 1
    drainage-basin: 1
    vast: 1
    forty-five: 1
    water: 1
    seaboard: 1
    pacific: 1
    draws: 1
    delaware: 1
    territories: 1
    river: 1
    supply: 1
    twenty-eight: 1
    idaho: 1
italy 1
    area: 1
    germany: 1
    austria: 1
    mississippi: 1
    france: 1
    proper: 1
    exceptionally: 1
    turkey: 1
    england: 1
    areas: 1
    combined: 1
    scotland: 1
    spain: 1
    wales: 1
    almost: 1
    fertile: 1
    region: 1
    wide: 1
    drainage-basin: 1
    portugal: 1
    ireland: 1
    valley: 1
main 1
    world--four: 1
    longest: 1
    river: 1
    branch: 1
    missouri: 1
    considering: 1
areas 1
    area: 1
    germany: 1
    austria: 1
    mississippi: 1
    france: 1
    proper: 1
    england: 1
    turkey: 1
    exceptionally: 1
    combined: 1
    scotland: 1
    italy: 1
    spain: 1
    wales: 1
    almost: 1
    fertile: 1
    region: 1
    wide: 1
    drainage-basin: 1
    portugal: 1
    ireland: 1
    valley: 1
seaboard 1
    spread: 1
    country: 1
    states: 1
    degrees: 1
    longitude: 1
    twenty-eight: 1
    drainage-basin: 1
    vast: 1
    forty-five: 1
    water: 1
    pacific: 1
    draws: 1
    delaware: 1
    territories: 1
    atlantic: 1
    supply: 1
    slope--a: 1
    river: 1
    idaho: 1
fertile 1
    area: 1
    germany: 1
    austria: 1
    mississippi: 1
    france: 1
    proper: 1
    exceptionally: 1
    turkey: 1
    england: 1
    areas: 1
    combined: 1
    scotland: 1
    italy: 1
    spain: 1
    wales: 1
    almost: 1
    region: 1
    wide: 1
    drainage-basin: 1
    portugal: 1
    ireland: 1
    valley: 1
ways 1
    contrary: 1
    river: 1
    remarkable: 1
    commonplace: 1
discharges 1
    water: 1
    st: 1
degrees 1
    spread: 1
    country: 1
    states: 1
    longitude: 1
    twenty-eight: 1
    drainage-basin: 1
    vast: 1
    forty-five: 1
    water: 1
    seaboard: 1
    pacific: 1
    draws: 1
    delaware: 1
    territories: 1
    atlantic: 1
    supply: 1
    slope--a: 1
    river: 1
    idaho: 1
wide 1
    area: 1
    germany: 1
    austria: 1
    mississippi: 1
    france: 1
    proper: 1
    exceptionally: 1
    turkey: 1
    england: 1
    areas: 1
    combined: 1
    scotland: 1
    italy: 1
    spain: 1
    wales: 1
    almost: 1
    fertile: 1
    region: 1
    drainage-basin: 1
    portugal: 1
    ireland: 1
    valley: 1
proper 1
    area: 1
    germany: 1
    austria: 1
    mississippi: 1
    france: 1
    england: 1
    turkey: 1
    exceptionally: 1
    areas: 1
    combined: 1
    scotland: 1
    italy: 1
    spain: 1
    wales: 1
    almost: 1
    fertile: 1
    region: 1
    wide: 1
    drainage-basin: 1
    portugal: 1
    ireland: 1
    valley: 1
keels 1
    mississippi: 1
    steamboats: 1
    navigable: 1
    water: 1
    fifty-four: 1
    hundreds: 1
    subordinate: 1
    carries: 1
    gulf: 1
    flats: 1
    rivers: 1
    receives: 1
portugal 1
    area: 1
    germany: 1
    austria: 1
    mississippi: 1
    france: 1
    proper: 1
    exceptionally: 1
    turkey: 1
    england: 1
    areas: 1
    combined: 1
    scotland: 1
    italy: 1
    spain: 1
    wales: 1
    almost: 1
    fertile: 1
    region: 1
    wide: 1
    drainage-basin: 1
    ireland: 1
    valley: 1
worth 1
    mississippi: 1
    reading: 1
uses 1
    ground: 1
    journey: 1
    seems: 1
    part: 1
    cover: 1
    crow: 1
    crookedest: 1
    six: 1
    safe: 1
    fly: 1
    seventy-five: 1
    river: 1
seventy-five 1
    ground: 1
    journey: 1
    seems: 1
    part: 1
    cover: 1
    crow: 1
    crookedest: 1
    six: 1
    safe: 1
    uses: 1
    river: 1
    fly: 1
valley 1
    area: 1
    germany: 1
    austria: 1
    mississippi: 1
    france: 1
    proper: 1
    exceptionally: 1
    turkey: 1
    england: 1
    areas: 1
    combined: 1
    scotland: 1
    italy: 1
    spain: 1
    wales: 1
    almost: 1
    fertile: 1
    region: 1
    wide: 1
    drainage-basin: 1
    portugal: 1
    ireland: 1
missouri 1
    main: 1
    longest: 1
    river: 1
    branch: 1
    world--four: 1
    considering: 1
wales 1
    area: 1
    germany: 1
    austria: 1
    mississippi: 1
    france: 1
    proper: 1
    exceptionally: 1
    turkey: 1
    england: 1
    areas: 1
    combined: 1
    scotland: 1
    italy: 1
    spain: 1
    almost: 1
    fertile: 1
    region: 1
    wide: 1
    drainage-basin: 1
    portugal: 1
    ireland: 1
    valley: 1
```

the first line is the target word and its frequency in the whole dictionary. Underneath is the associated words and their frequency in same sentence with target word. Like the first dictionary, the profile associated with "mississippi" will contain references to "worth" and "reading" and their word frequency in sentence is 1, but the word frequency of mississippi is 3 in entire dictionary. And I want to sort the word frequency of target word in descending order. Anyone can help?

Comment: fix the indentation first please

Comment: if not a typo: `file = open('sample.txt', 'r')` missing `open`, and `.lower()`. This does not seem like your working code.

Comment: @Blownhither Ma, I have corrected my silly mistakes. But things still not right..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sum the word frequency of value by key and list associated words](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50478655/sum-the-word-frequency-of-value-by-key-and-list-associated-words)

Answer (score 1):

It's not exactly clear neither from your desired output nor from your code what exactly are you trying to achieve but if it's just counting words in individual sentences then the strategy should be:

1. Read your `common.txt` into a `set` for a fast lookup.
2. Read your `sample.txt` and split on `.` to get individual sentences.
3. Clear up all non-word characters (you'll have to define them or to use regex `\b` to capture word boundaries) and replace them with whitespace.
4. Split on whitespace and count the words not present in the `set` from *Step 1*.

So:

```
import collections

with open("common.txt", "r") as f:  # open the `common.txt` for reading
    common_words = {l.strip().lower() for l in f}  # read each line and and add it to a set

interpunction = ";,'\""  # define word separating characters and create a translation table
trans_table = str.maketrans(interpunction, " " * len(interpunction))

sentences_counter = []  # a list to hold a word count for each sentence
with open("sample.txt", "r") as f:  # open the `sample.txt` for reading
    # read the whole file to include linebreaks and split on `.` to get individual sentences
    sentences = [s for s in f.read().split(".") if s.strip()]  # ignore empty sentences
    for sentence in sentences:  # iterate over each sentence
        sentence = sentence.translate(trans_table)  # replace the interpunction with spaces
        word_counter = collections.defaultdict(int)  # a string:int default dict for counting
        for word in sentence.split():  # split the sentence and iterate over the words
            if word.lower() not in common_words:  # count only words not in the common.txt
                word_counter[word.lower()] += 1
        sentences_counter.append(word_counter)  # add the current sentence word count
```

*NOTE: On Python 2.x use `string.maketrans()` instead of `str.maketrans()`.*

This will produce `sentences_counter` containing a dictionary count for each of the sentences in `sample.txt`, where the key is an actual word and its associate value is the word count. You can print the result as:

```
for i, v in enumerate(sentences_counter):
    print("Sentence #{}:".format(i+1))
    print("\n".join("\t{}: {}".format(w, c) for w, c in v.items()))
```

Which will produce (for your sample data):

```
Sentence #1:
    area: 1
    drainage-basin: 1
    great: 1
    combined: 1
    areas: 1
    england: 1
    wales: 1
    wide: 1
    region: 1
    fertile: 1
Sentence #2:
    mississippi: 1
    valley: 1
    proper: 1
    exceptionally: 1
```

Keep in mind that (English) language is more complex than this - for example, "*A cat wiggles **its** tail when **it's** angry so stay away from **it**.*" will vastly differ in dependence on how you treat an apostrophe. Also, a dot doesn't necessarily denote the end of a sentence. You should look into [**NLP**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural-language_processing) if you want to do serious linguistic analysis.

**UPDATE**: While i don't see the usefulness of reiterating over each word repeating the data (the count won't ever change within a sentence) if you want to print each word and nest all the other counts underneath you can just add an inner loop while printing:

```
for i, v in enumerate(sentences_counter):
    print("Sentence #{}:".format(i+1))
    for word, count in v.items():
        print("\t{} {}".format(word, count))
        print("\n".join("\t\t{}: {}".format(w, c) for w, c in v.items() if w != word))
```

Which will give you:

```
Sentence #1:
    area 1
        drainage-basin: 1
        great: 1
        combined: 1
        areas: 1
        england: 1
        wales: 1
        wide: 1
        region: 1
        fertile: 1
    drainage-basin 1
        area: 1
        great: 1
        combined: 1
        areas: 1
        england: 1
        wales: 1
        wide: 1
        region: 1
        fertile: 1
    great 1
        area: 1
        drainage-basin: 1
        combined: 1
        areas: 1
        england: 1
        wales: 1
        wide: 1
        region: 1
        fertile: 1
    combined 1
        area: 1
        drainage-basin: 1
        great: 1
        areas: 1
        england: 1
        wales: 1
        wide: 1
        region: 1
        fertile: 1
    areas 1
        area: 1
        drainage-basin: 1
        great: 1
        combined: 1
        england: 1
        wales: 1
        wide: 1
        region: 1
        fertile: 1
    england 1
        area: 1
        drainage-basin: 1
        great: 1
        combined: 1
        areas: 1
        wales: 1
        wide: 1
        region: 1
        fertile: 1
    wales 1
        area: 1
        drainage-basin: 1
        great: 1
        combined: 1
        areas: 1
        england: 1
        wide: 1
        region: 1
        fertile: 1
    wide 1
        area: 1
        drainage-basin: 1
        great: 1
        combined: 1
        areas: 1
        england: 1
        wales: 1
        region: 1
        fertile: 1
    region 1
        area: 1
        drainage-basin: 1
        great: 1
        combined: 1
        areas: 1
        england: 1
        wales: 1
        wide: 1
        fertile: 1
    fertile 1
        area: 1
        drainage-basin: 1
        great: 1
        combined: 1
        areas: 1
        england: 1
        wales: 1
        wide: 1
        region: 1
Sentence #2:
    mississippi 1
        valley: 1
        proper: 1
        exceptionally: 1
    valley 1
        mississippi: 1
        proper: 1
        exceptionally: 1
    proper 1
        mississippi: 1
        valley: 1
        exceptionally: 1
    exceptionally 1
        mississippi: 1
        valley: 1
        proper: 1
```

Feel free to remove the sentence number printing and reduce one of the tab indentations to get something more of a desired output from your question. You can also build a tree-like dictionary instead of printing everything to the STDOUT if that's more what you fancy.

**UPDATE 2**: If you want, you don't have to use a `set` for the `common_words`. In this case it's pretty much interchangeable with a `list` so you can use [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) instead of [set comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets) (i.e. replace curly with square brackets) but looking through a `list` is an `O(n)` operation whereas `set` lookup is an `O(1)` operation and therefore a `set` is preferred here. Not to mention the collateral benefit of automatic de-duplication in case the `common.txt` has duplicate words.

As for the [`collections.defaultdict()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) it's there just to save us some coding/checking by automatically initializing the dictionary to a key whenever it's requested - without it you'd have to do it manually:

```
with open("common.txt", "r") as f:  # open the `common.txt` for reading
    common_words = {l.strip().lower() for l in f}  # read each line and and add it to a set

interpunction = ";,'\""  # define word separating characters and create a translation table
trans_table = str.maketrans(interpunction, " " * len(interpunction))

sentences_counter = []  # a list to hold a word count for each sentence
with open("sample.txt", "r") as f:  # open the `sample.txt` for reading
    # read the whole file to include linebreaks and split on `.` to get individual sentences
    sentences = [s for s in f.read().split(".") if s.strip()]  # ignore empty sentences
    for sentence in sentences:  # iterate over each sentence
        sentence = sentence.translate(trans_table)  # replace the interpunction with spaces
        word_counter = {}  # initialize a word counting dictionary
        for word in sentence.split():  # split the sentence and iterate over the words
            word = word.lower()  # turn the word to lowercase
            if word not in common_words:  # count only words not in the common.txt
                word_counter[word] = word_counter.get(word, 0) + 1  # increase the last count
        sentences_counter.append(word_counter)  # add the current sentence word count
```

**UPDATE 3**: If you just want a raw word list across all sentences as it seems from your last update to the question, you don't even need to consider the sentences themselves - just add a dot to the interpunction list, read the file line by line, split on whitespace and count the words as before:

```
import collections

with open("common.txt", "r") as f:  # open the `common.txt` for reading
    common_words = {l.strip().lower() for l in f}  # read each line and and add it to a set

interpunction = ";,'\"."  # define word separating characters and create a translation table
trans_table = str.maketrans(interpunction, " " * len(interpunction))

sentences_counter = []  # a list to hold a word count for each sentence

word_counter = collections.defaultdict(int)  # a string:int default dict for counting
with open("sample.txt", "r") as f:  # open the `sample.txt` for reading
    for line in f:  # read the file line by line
        for word in line.translate(trans_table).split():  # remove interpunction and split
            if word.lower() not in common_words:  # count only words not in the common.txt
                word_counter[word.lower()] += 1  # increase the count

print("\n".join("{}: {}".format(w, c) for w, c in word_counter.items()))  # print the counts
```

Comment: Hi zwer, sorry for the unclear description. it is the practice material from uni. the output should be like dictionary in dictionary. For example, I use area 1 as my main word and in its dictionary, drainage-basin counts once then it shows: drainage-basin: 1 and when use drainage-basin 1 as main word, area count 1, shows area: 1. Is there any way to use the knowledge of list, dictionary and word count frequency to get the desired output?

Comment: @JimChi - And by what logic would you chose the _main word_ to nest the other words under? And would that transcend sentences? There is nothing in your question that would indicate such constraint.

Comment: the main word would go through each words except common words and create a profile for itself and count frequency of other words. the words which are listed in dictionary are in the same sentences where the main words are. If the main words shows twice or more in one sentence, still count as one.

Comment: The sample.txt is only a part of the whole paragraph and like main word of area would appear in other sentences. like example:the mississippi is well worth reading about. it is not a commonplace river, but on the contrary is in all ways remarkable. considering the Missouri its main branch, it is the longest river in the world--four thousand three hundred miles. the river shows twice in sentences so the dictionary looks like river 2 (counts how many times show in whole paragraph) mississippi: 1 reading: 1 ... ; then main word changes to mississippi 1 river: 1 reading: 1

Comment: Thank you so much for the solution. it works. But so far I haven't learnt how to use set and you use import collection to pick words, which I may need to study a bit. Do you have solution by using function of list, dictionary, word count?

Comment: Thank you for so much help for it. But I still have a question about the output and I have uploaded the whole sample paragraph. Like first line, line breaks after commonplace and river shows in sentence #3 while it should be in sentence #2. How to solve it? Also, the desired output shows word "river" is listed in paragraph 4 times, so I need to modify " #print("\t{} {}".format(word, count)) " ? The profile associated words are in the same sentence as river, so river is the target word and following are associated word and count.

Comment: Thank you so much for help. I am nearly reaching the result. But is there any way to sort the key by value in dictionary without importing modules? And in the first update: for word, count in v.items(): it has the AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'items' then how can I display every word and its count in the same sentence of target word? I have update my question and code for you to have a look

Comment: @JimChi - You keep changing your desired output and it's becoming hard to follow, plus with so many changes the SO community doesn't benefit from our little exchange over here. You're also introducing new concepts like _target word_ so it's no longer clear whether you want your word count to be based on individual sentences or the whole text etc. Can you post a new question with precisely defined requirements vs what you're currently getting?

Comment: Mr. zwer, I have raise a new question for my problem. Could you help me a bit? I have obtained the current dictionary but failed to count the frequency of target word. Thanks.