# Sum the word frequency of value by key and list associated words

Tags: python, word-frequency

I have a dictionary like below:

```
[{'mississippi': 1, 'worth': 1, 'reading': 1},
 {'commonplace': 1, 'river': 1, 'contrary': 1, 'ways': 1, 'remarkable': 1},
 {'considering': 1, 'missouri': 1, 'main': 1, 'branch': 1, 'longest': 1, 'river': 1, 
  'world--four': 1},
 {'seems': 1, 'safe': 1, 'crookedest': 1, 'river': 1, 'part': 1, 'journey': 1, 'uses': 1, 
  'cover': 1, 'ground': 1, 'crow': 1, 'fly': 1, 'six': 1, 'seventy-five': 1},
 {'discharges': 1, 'water': 1, 'st': 1},
 {'lawrence': 1, 'twenty-five': 1, 'rhine': 1, 'thirty-eight': 1, 'thames': 1},
 {'river': 1, 'vast': 1, 'drainage-basin:': 1, 'draws': 1, 'water': 1, 'supply': 1, 
  'twenty-eight': 1, 'states': 1, 'territories': 1, 'delaware': 1, 'atlantic': 1, 
  'seaboard': 1, 'country': 1, 'idaho': 1, 'pacific': 1, 'slope--a': 1, 'spread': 1, 
  'forty-five': 1, 'degrees': 1, 'longitude': 1},
 {'mississippi': 1, 'receives': 1, 'carries': 1, 'gulf': 1, 'water': 1, 'fifty-four': 1, 
  'subordinate': 1, 'rivers': 1, 'navigable': 1, 'steamboats': 1, 'hundreds': 1, 'flats': 1, 
  'keels': 1},
 {'area': 1, 'drainage-basin': 1, 'combined': 1, 'areas': 1, 'england': 1, 'wales': 1, 
  'scotland': 1, 'ireland': 1, 'france': 1, 'spain': 1, 'portugal': 1, 'germany': 1, 
  'austria': 1, 'italy': 1, 'turkey': 1, 'almost': 1, 'wide': 1, 'region': 1, 'fertile': 1, 
  'mississippi': 1, 'valley': 1, 'proper': 1, 'exceptionally': 1}]
```

And I want to change it to my desired output like below to calculate score of similarity between two words:

```
river 4
    ground: 1
    journey: 1
    longitude: 1
    main: 1
    world--four: 1
    contrary: 1
    cover: 1
    delaware: 1
    remarkable: 1
    vast: 1
    forty-five: 1
    crookedest: 1
    territories: 1
    spread: 1
    country: 1
    longest: 1
    fly: 1
    atlantic: 1
    crow: 1
    supply: 1
    seems: 1
    idaho: 1
    seaboard: 1
    states: 1
    ways: 1
    degrees: 1
    part: 1
    twenty-eight: 1
    pacific: 1
    branch: 1
    water: 1
    considering: 1
    six: 1
    safe: 1
    commonplace: 1
    draws: 1
    drainage-basin: 1
    uses: 1
    seventy-five: 1
    slope--a: 1
    missouri: 1
mississippi 3
    area: 1
    steamboats: 1
    germany: 1
    reading: 1
    france: 1
    proper: 1
    fifty-four: 1
    turkey: 1
    exceptionally: 1
    areas: 1
    carries: 1
    combined: 1
    flats: 1
    receives: 1
    england: 1
    italy: 1
    scotland: 1
    wales: 1
    almost: 1
    navigable: 1
    austria: 1
    region: 1
    wide: 1
    spain: 1
    subordinate: 1
    drainage-basin: 1
    hundreds: 1
    keels: 1
    portugal: 1
    water: 1
    gulf: 1
    ireland: 1
    rivers: 1
    valley: 1
    fertile: 1
    worth: 1
water 3
    steamboats: 1
    spread: 1
    country: 1
    states: 1
    longitude: 1
    fifty-four: 1
    pacific: 1
    vast: 1
    subordinate: 1
    carries: 1
    keels: 1
    flats: 1
    supply: 1
    receives: 1
    atlantic: 1
    forty-five: 1
    river: 1
    rivers: 1
    idaho: 1
    mississippi: 1
    seaboard: 1
    navigable: 1
    discharges: 1
    degrees: 1
    twenty-eight: 1
    drainage-basin: 1
    hundreds: 1
    st: 1
    gulf: 1
    draws: 1
    delaware: 1
    territories: 1
    slope--a: 1
drainage-basin 2
    area: 1
    spread: 1
    country: 1
    states: 1
    mississippi: 1
    longitude: 1
    france: 1
    proper: 1
    vast: 1
    turkey: 1
    forty-five: 1
    areas: 1
    combined: 1
    germany: 1
    exceptionally: 1
    valley: 1
    supply: 1
    fertile: 1
    atlantic: 1
    italy: 1
    river: 1
    idaho: 1
    wales: 1
    almost: 1
    seaboard: 1
    spain: 1
    austria: 1
    region: 1
    degrees: 1
    twenty-eight: 1
    wide: 1
    england: 1
    portugal: 1
    water: 1
    ireland: 1
    pacific: 1
    draws: 1
    delaware: 1
    territories: 1
    scotland: 1
    slope--a: 1
area 1
    germany: 1
    austria: 1
    mississippi: 1
    france: 1
    proper: 1
    england: 1
    turkey: 1
    exceptionally: 1
    areas: 1
    combined: 1
    scotland: 1
    italy: 1
    spain: 1
    wales: 1
    almost: 1
    fertile: 1
    region: 1
    wide: 1
    drainage-basin: 1
    portugal: 1
    ireland: 1
    valley: 1
journey 1
    ground: 1
    seems: 1
    part: 1
    cover: 1
    crow: 1
    crookedest: 1
    six: 1
    safe: 1
    uses: 1
    seventy-five: 1
    river: 1
    fly: 1
seems 1
    ground: 1
    journey: 1
    part: 1
    cover: 1
    crow: 1
    crookedest: 1
    six: 1
    safe: 1
    uses: 1
    seventy-five: 1
    river: 1
    fly: 1
states 1
    spread: 1
    country: 1
    degrees: 1
    longitude: 1
    twenty-eight: 1
    drainage-basin: 1
    vast: 1
    forty-five: 1
    water: 1
    seaboard: 1
    pacific: 1
    draws: 1
    delaware: 1
    territories: 1
    atlantic: 1
    supply: 1
    slope--a: 1
    river: 1
    idaho: 1
slope--a 1
    spread: 1
    country: 1
    states: 1
    degrees: 1
    longitude: 1
    drainage-basin: 1
    vast: 1
    forty-five: 1
    water: 1
    seaboard: 1
    pacific: 1
    draws: 1
    delaware: 1
    territories: 1
    atlantic: 1
    supply: 1
    twenty-eight: 1
    river: 1
    idaho: 1
remarkable 1
    contrary: 1
    river: 1
    commonplace: 1
    ways: 1
vast 1
    spread: 1
    country: 1
    states: 1
    degrees: 1
    longitude: 1
    twenty-eight: 1
    drainage-basin: 1
    pacific: 1
    forty-five: 1
    water: 1
    seaboard: 1
    draws: 1
    delaware: 1
    territories: 1
    atlantic: 1
    supply: 1
    slope--a: 1
    river: 1
    idaho: 1
forty-five 1
    spread: 1
    longitude: 1
    country: 1
    states: 1
    degrees: 1
    slope--a: 1
    drainage-basin: 1
    vast: 1
    pacific: 1
    water: 1
    seaboard: 1
    draws: 1
    delaware: 1
    territories: 1
    atlantic: 1
    supply: 1
    twenty-eight: 1
    river: 1
    idaho: 1
crookedest 1
    ground: 1
    journey: 1
    seems: 1
    part: 1
    cover: 1
    crow: 1
    six: 1
    safe: 1
    uses: 1
    seventy-five: 1
    river: 1
    fly: 1
carries 1
    mississippi: 1
    steamboats: 1
    navigable: 1
    fifty-four: 1
    keels: 1
    hundreds: 1
    subordinate: 1
    water: 1
    gulf: 1
    flats: 1
    rivers: 1
    receives: 1
germany 1
    area: 1
    austria: 1
    mississippi: 1
    france: 1
    proper: 1
    exceptionally: 1
    turkey: 1
    england: 1
    areas: 1
    combined: 1
    scotland: 1
    italy: 1
    spain: 1
    wales: 1
    almost: 1
    fertile: 1
    region: 1
    wide: 1
    drainage-basin: 1
    portugal: 1
    ireland: 1
    valley: 1
longest 1
    main: 1
    river: 1
    world--four: 1
    branch: 1
    missouri: 1
    considering: 1
flats 1
    mississippi: 1
    steamboats: 1
    navigable: 1
    carries: 1
    fifty-four: 1
    keels: 1
    hundreds: 1
    subordinate: 1
    water: 1
    gulf: 1
    rivers: 1
    receives: 1
supply 1
    spread: 1
    longitude: 1
    country: 1
    states: 1
    degrees: 1
    slope--a: 1
    drainage-basin: 1
    vast: 1
    forty-five: 1
    water: 1
    seaboard: 1
    pacific: 1
    draws: 1
    delaware: 1
    territories: 1
    atlantic: 1
    twenty-eight: 1
    river: 1
    idaho: 1
receives 1
    mississippi: 1
    steamboats: 1
    navigable: 1
    carries: 1
    fifty-four: 1
    keels: 1
    hundreds: 1
    subordinate: 1
    water: 1
    gulf: 1
    flats: 1
    rivers: 1
crow 1
    ground: 1
    journey: 1
    seems: 1
    part: 1
    cover: 1
    crookedest: 1
    six: 1
    safe: 1
    uses: 1
    seventy-five: 1
    river: 1
    fly: 1
scotland 1
    area: 1
    germany: 1
    austria: 1
    mississippi: 1
    france: 1
    proper: 1
    exceptionally: 1
    turkey: 1
    england: 1
    areas: 1
    combined: 1
    spain: 1
    italy: 1
    wales: 1
    almost: 1
    fertile: 1
    region: 1
    wide: 1
    drainage-basin: 1
    portugal: 1
    ireland: 1
    valley: 1
country 1
    spread: 1
    idaho: 1
    states: 1
    degrees: 1
    longitude: 1
    twenty-eight: 1
    drainage-basin: 1
    vast: 1
    forty-five: 1
    water: 1
    seaboard: 1
    pacific: 1
    draws: 1
    delaware: 1
    territories: 1
    atlantic: 1
    supply: 1
    slope--a: 1
    river: 1
thames 1
    thirty-eight: 1
    rhine: 1
    lawrence: 1
    twenty-five: 1
england 1
    area: 1
    germany: 1
    austria: 1
    mississippi: 1
    france: 1
    proper: 1
    exceptionally: 1
    turkey: 1
    region: 1
    areas: 1
    combined: 1
    scotland: 1
    italy: 1
    spain: 1
    wales: 1
    almost: 1
    fertile: 1
    wide: 1
    drainage-basin: 1
    portugal: 1
    ireland: 1
    valley: 1
navigable 1
    mississippi: 1
    steamboats: 1
    carries: 1
    fifty-four: 1
    keels: 1
    hundreds: 1
    subordinate: 1
    water: 1
    gulf: 1
    flats: 1
    rivers: 1
    receives: 1
austria 1
    area: 1
    germany: 1
    mississippi: 1
    france: 1
    proper: 1
    region: 1
    turkey: 1
    england: 1
    areas: 1
    combined: 1
    exceptionally: 1
    scotland: 1
    italy: 1
    spain: 1
    wales: 1
    almost: 1
    fertile: 1
    wide: 1
    drainage-basin: 1
    portugal: 1
    ireland: 1
    valley: 1
rhine 1
    thirty-eight: 1
    thames: 1
    lawrence: 1
    twenty-five: 1
part 1
    ground: 1
    journey: 1
    seems: 1
    cover: 1
    crow: 1
    crookedest: 1
    six: 1
    safe: 1
    uses: 1
    seventy-five: 1
    river: 1
    fly: 1
twenty-eight 1
    spread: 1
    country: 1
    states: 1
    degrees: 1
    longitude: 1
    drainage-basin: 1
    vast: 1
    forty-five: 1
    water: 1
    seaboard: 1
    pacific: 1
    draws: 1
    delaware: 1
    territories: 1
    atlantic: 1
    supply: 1
    slope--a: 1
    river: 1
    idaho: 1
branch 1
    main: 1
    longest: 1
    river: 1
    world--four: 1
    missouri: 1
    considering: 1
hundreds 1
    mississippi: 1
    steamboats: 1
    navigable: 1
    carries: 1
    fifty-four: 1
    keels: 1
    subordinate: 1
    water: 1
    gulf: 1
    flats: 1
    rivers: 1
    receives: 1
st 1
    water: 1
    discharges: 1
considering 1
    main: 1
    longest: 1
    river: 1
    world--four: 1
    branch: 1
    missouri: 1
six 1
    ground: 1
    journey: 1
    seems: 1
    part: 1
    cover: 1
    crow: 1
    crookedest: 1
    fly: 1
    safe: 1
    uses: 1
    seventy-five: 1
    river: 1
gulf 1
    mississippi: 1
    steamboats: 1
    navigable: 1
    carries: 1
    fifty-four: 1
    keels: 1
    hundreds: 1
    subordinate: 1
    water: 1
    flats: 1
    rivers: 1
    receives: 1
ireland 1
    area: 1
    germany: 1
    austria: 1
    mississippi: 1
    france: 1
    proper: 1
    exceptionally: 1
    turkey: 1
    england: 1
    areas: 1
    combined: 1
    scotland: 1
    italy: 1
    spain: 1
    wales: 1
    almost: 1
    fertile: 1
    region: 1
    wide: 1
    drainage-basin: 1
    portugal: 1
    valley: 1
safe 1
    ground: 1
    journey: 1
    seems: 1
    part: 1
    cover: 1
    crow: 1
    crookedest: 1
    six: 1
    uses: 1
    seventy-five: 1
    river: 1
    fly: 1
commonplace 1
    contrary: 1
    river: 1
    remarkable: 1
    ways: 1
draws 1
    spread: 1
    longitude: 1
    country: 1
    states: 1
    degrees: 1
    slope--a: 1
    drainage-basin: 1
    vast: 1
    forty-five: 1
    water: 1
    seaboard: 1
    pacific: 1
    supply: 1
    delaware: 1
    territories: 1
    atlantic: 1
    twenty-eight: 1
    river: 1
    idaho: 1
delaware 1
    spread: 1
    longitude: 1
    country: 1
    states: 1
    degrees: 1
    slope--a: 1
    drainage-basin: 1
    vast: 1
    forty-five: 1
    water: 1
    seaboard: 1
    pacific: 1
    draws: 1
    territories: 1
    atlantic: 1
    supply: 1
    twenty-eight: 1
    river: 1
    idaho: 1
thirty-eight 1
    thames: 1
    rhine: 1
    lawrence: 1
    twenty-five: 1
longitude 1
    spread: 1
    country: 1
    states: 1
    degrees: 1
    slope--a: 1
    drainage-basin: 1
    vast: 1
    forty-five: 1
    water: 1
    seaboard: 1
    pacific: 1
    draws: 1
    delaware: 1
    territories: 1
    atlantic: 1
    supply: 1
    twenty-eight: 1
    river: 1
    idaho: 1
world--four 1
    main: 1
    longest: 1
    river: 1
    branch: 1
    missouri: 1
    considering: 1
lawrence 1
    thirty-eight: 1
    thames: 1
    rhine: 1
    twenty-five: 1
ground 1
    journey: 1
    seems: 1
    part: 1
    cover: 1
    crow: 1
    crookedest: 1
    six: 1
    safe: 1
    uses: 1
    seventy-five: 1
    river: 1
    fly: 1
steamboats 1
    mississippi: 1
    navigable: 1
    carries: 1
    fifty-four: 1
    keels: 1
    hundreds: 1
    subordinate: 1
    water: 1
    gulf: 1
    flats: 1
    rivers: 1
    receives: 1
spread 1
    seaboard: 1
    country: 1
    states: 1
    degrees: 1
    longitude: 1
    twenty-eight: 1
    drainage-basin: 1
    vast: 1
    forty-five: 1
    water: 1
    pacific: 1
    draws: 1
    delaware: 1
    territories: 1
    atlantic: 1
    supply: 1
    slope--a: 1
    river: 1
    idaho: 1
idaho 1
    spread: 1
    country: 1
    states: 1
    degrees: 1
    longitude: 1
    twenty-eight: 1
    drainage-basin: 1
    vast: 1
    forty-five: 1
    water: 1
    seaboard: 1
    pacific: 1
    draws: 1
    delaware: 1
    territories: 1
    atlantic: 1
    supply: 1
    slope--a: 1
    river: 1
reading 1
    mississippi: 1
    worth: 1
almost 1
    area: 1
    germany: 1
    austria: 1
    france: 1
    proper: 1
    england: 1
    turkey: 1
    exceptionally: 1
    areas: 1
    combined: 1
    scotland: 1
    italy: 1
    spain: 1
    wales: 1
    mississippi: 1
    fertile: 1
    region: 1
    wide: 1
    drainage-basin: 1
    portugal: 1
    ireland: 1
    valley: 1
contrary 1
    river: 1
    remarkable: 1
    commonplace: 1
    ways: 1
cover 1
    ground: 1
    journey: 1
    seems: 1
    part: 1
    crow: 1
    crookedest: 1
    six: 1
    safe: 1
    uses: 1
    seventy-five: 1
    river: 1
    fly: 1
france 1
    area: 1
    germany: 1
    austria: 1
    mississippi: 1
    proper: 1
    england: 1
    turkey: 1
    exceptionally: 1
    areas: 1
    combined: 1
    scotland: 1
    italy: 1
    spain: 1
    wales: 1
    almost: 1
    fertile: 1
    region: 1
    wide: 1
    drainage-basin: 1
    portugal: 1
    ireland: 1
    valley: 1
spain 1
    area: 1
    germany: 1
    austria: 1
    mississippi: 1
    france: 1
    proper: 1
    exceptionally: 1
    turkey: 1
    england: 1
    areas: 1
    combined: 1
    scotland: 1
    italy: 1
    wales: 1
    almost: 1
    fertile: 1
    region: 1
    wide: 1
    drainage-basin: 1
    portugal: 1
    ireland: 1
    valley: 1
pacific 1
    spread: 1
    longitude: 1
    country: 1
    states: 1
    degrees: 1
    slope--a: 1
    drainage-basin: 1
    vast: 1
    forty-five: 1
    water: 1
    seaboard: 1
    draws: 1
    delaware: 1
    territories: 1
    atlantic: 1
    supply: 1
    twenty-eight: 1
    river: 1
    idaho: 1
turkey 1
    area: 1
    germany: 1
    austria: 1
    mississippi: 1
    france: 1
    proper: 1
    exceptionally: 1
    england: 1
    areas: 1
    combined: 1
    scotland: 1
    italy: 1
    spain: 1
    wales: 1
    almost: 1
    fertile: 1
    region: 1
    wide: 1
    drainage-basin: 1
    portugal: 1
    ireland: 1
    valley: 1
fifty-four 1
    mississippi: 1
    steamboats: 1
    navigable: 1
    carries: 1
    hundreds: 1
    keels: 1
    subordinate: 1
    water: 1
    gulf: 1
    flats: 1
    rivers: 1
    receives: 1
subordinate 1
    mississippi: 1
    steamboats: 1
    navigable: 1
    carries: 1
    fifty-four: 1
    keels: 1
    hundreds: 1
    water: 1
    gulf: 1
    flats: 1
    rivers: 1
    receives: 1
territories 1
    spread: 1
    idaho: 1
    states: 1
    degrees: 1
    longitude: 1
    twenty-eight: 1
    drainage-basin: 1
    vast: 1
    forty-five: 1
    water: 1
    seaboard: 1
    pacific: 1
    draws: 1
    delaware: 1
    supply: 1
    atlantic: 1
    slope--a: 1
    river: 1
    country: 1
combined 1
    area: 1
    germany: 1
    austria: 1
    mississippi: 1
    france: 1
    proper: 1
    exceptionally: 1
    turkey: 1
    england: 1
    areas: 1
    scotland: 1
    italy: 1
    spain: 1
    wales: 1
    almost: 1
    fertile: 1
    region: 1
    wide: 1
    drainage-basin: 1
    portugal: 1
    ireland: 1
    valley: 1
exceptionally 1
    area: 1
    germany: 1
    austria: 1
    mississippi: 1
    france: 1
    proper: 1
    england: 1
    turkey: 1
    region: 1
    areas: 1
    combined: 1
    scotland: 1
    italy: 1
    spain: 1
    wales: 1
    almost: 1
    fertile: 1
    wide: 1
    drainage-basin: 1
    portugal: 1
    ireland: 1
    valley: 1
region 1
    area: 1
    germany: 1
    austria: 1
    mississippi: 1
    france: 1
    proper: 1
    exceptionally: 1
    turkey: 1
    england: 1
    areas: 1
    combined: 1
    scotland: 1
    italy: 1
    spain: 1
    wales: 1
    almost: 1
    fertile: 1
    wide: 1
    drainage-basin: 1
    portugal: 1
    ireland: 1
    valley: 1
twenty-five 1
    thirty-eight: 1
    thames: 1
    lawrence: 1
    rhine: 1
rivers 1
    mississippi: 1
    steamboats: 1
    navigable: 1
    carries: 1
    fifty-four: 1
    keels: 1
    hundreds: 1
    subordinate: 1
    water: 1
    gulf: 1
    flats: 1
    receives: 1
fly 1
    ground: 1
    journey: 1
    seems: 1
    part: 1
    cover: 1
    crow: 1
    crookedest: 1
    six: 1
    safe: 1
    uses: 1
    seventy-five: 1
    river: 1
atlantic 1
    spread: 1
    longitude: 1
    country: 1
    states: 1
    degrees: 1
    slope--a: 1
    drainage-basin: 1
    vast: 1
    forty-five: 1
    water: 1
    seaboard: 1
    pacific: 1
    draws: 1
    delaware: 1
    territories: 1
    river: 1
    supply: 1
    twenty-eight: 1
    idaho: 1
italy 1
    area: 1
    germany: 1
    austria: 1
    mississippi: 1
    france: 1
    proper: 1
    exceptionally: 1
    turkey: 1
    england: 1
    areas: 1
    combined: 1
    scotland: 1
    spain: 1
    wales: 1
    almost: 1
    fertile: 1
    region: 1
    wide: 1
    drainage-basin: 1
    portugal: 1
    ireland: 1
    valley: 1
main 1
    world--four: 1
    longest: 1
    river: 1
    branch: 1
    missouri: 1
    considering: 1
areas 1
    area: 1
    germany: 1
    austria: 1
    mississippi: 1
    france: 1
    proper: 1
    england: 1
    turkey: 1
    exceptionally: 1
    combined: 1
    scotland: 1
    italy: 1
    spain: 1
    wales: 1
    almost: 1
    fertile: 1
    region: 1
    wide: 1
    drainage-basin: 1
    portugal: 1
    ireland: 1
    valley: 1
seaboard 1
    spread: 1
    country: 1
    states: 1
    degrees: 1
    longitude: 1
    twenty-eight: 1
    drainage-basin: 1
    vast: 1
    forty-five: 1
    water: 1
    pacific: 1
    draws: 1
    delaware: 1
    territories: 1
    atlantic: 1
    supply: 1
    slope--a: 1
    river: 1
    idaho: 1
fertile 1
    area: 1
    germany: 1
    austria: 1
    mississippi: 1
    france: 1
    proper: 1
    exceptionally: 1
    turkey: 1
    england: 1
    areas: 1
    combined: 1
    scotland: 1
    italy: 1
    spain: 1
    wales: 1
    almost: 1
    region: 1
    wide: 1
    drainage-basin: 1
    portugal: 1
    ireland: 1
    valley: 1
ways 1
    contrary: 1
    river: 1
    remarkable: 1
    commonplace: 1
discharges 1
    water: 1
    st: 1
degrees 1
    spread: 1
    country: 1
    states: 1
    longitude: 1
    twenty-eight: 1
    drainage-basin: 1
    vast: 1
    forty-five: 1
    water: 1
    seaboard: 1
    pacific: 1
    draws: 1
    delaware: 1
    territories: 1
    atlantic: 1
    supply: 1
    slope--a: 1
    river: 1
    idaho: 1
wide 1
    area: 1
    germany: 1
    austria: 1
    mississippi: 1
    france: 1
    proper: 1
    exceptionally: 1
    turkey: 1
    england: 1
    areas: 1
    combined: 1
    scotland: 1
    italy: 1
    spain: 1
    wales: 1
    almost: 1
    fertile: 1
    region: 1
    drainage-basin: 1
    portugal: 1
    ireland: 1
    valley: 1
proper 1
    area: 1
    germany: 1
    austria: 1
    mississippi: 1
    france: 1
    england: 1
    turkey: 1
    exceptionally: 1
    areas: 1
    combined: 1
    scotland: 1
    italy: 1
    spain: 1
    wales: 1
    almost: 1
    fertile: 1
    region: 1
    wide: 1
    drainage-basin: 1
    portugal: 1
    ireland: 1
    valley: 1
keels 1
    mississippi: 1
    steamboats: 1
    navigable: 1
    water: 1
    fifty-four: 1
    hundreds: 1
    subordinate: 1
    carries: 1
    gulf: 1
    flats: 1
    rivers: 1
    receives: 1
portugal 1
    area: 1
    germany: 1
    austria: 1
    mississippi: 1
    france: 1
    proper: 1
    exceptionally: 1
    turkey: 1
    england: 1
    areas: 1
    combined: 1
    scotland: 1
    italy: 1
    spain: 1
    wales: 1
    almost: 1
    fertile: 1
    region: 1
    wide: 1
    drainage-basin: 1
    ireland: 1
    valley: 1
worth 1
    mississippi: 1
    reading: 1
uses 1
    ground: 1
    journey: 1
    seems: 1
    part: 1
    cover: 1
    crow: 1
    crookedest: 1
    six: 1
    safe: 1
    fly: 1
    seventy-five: 1
    river: 1
seventy-five 1
    ground: 1
    journey: 1
    seems: 1
    part: 1
    cover: 1
    crow: 1
    crookedest: 1
    six: 1
    safe: 1
    uses: 1
    river: 1
    fly: 1
valley 1
    area: 1
    germany: 1
    austria: 1
    mississippi: 1
    france: 1
    proper: 1
    exceptionally: 1
    turkey: 1
    england: 1
    areas: 1
    combined: 1
    scotland: 1
    italy: 1
    spain: 1
    wales: 1
    almost: 1
    fertile: 1
    region: 1
    wide: 1
    drainage-basin: 1
    portugal: 1
    ireland: 1
missouri 1
    main: 1
    longest: 1
    river: 1
    branch: 1
    world--four: 1
    considering: 1
wales 1
    area: 1
    germany: 1
    austria: 1
    mississippi: 1
    france: 1
    proper: 1
    exceptionally: 1
    turkey: 1
    england: 1
    areas: 1
    combined: 1
    scotland: 1
    italy: 1
    spain: 1
    almost: 1
    fertile: 1
    region: 1
    wide: 1
    drainage-basin: 1
    portugal: 1
    ireland: 1
    valley: 1
```

the first line is the target word and its frequency in the whole dictionary. Underneath is the associated words and their frequency in same sentence with target word. Like the first dictionary, the profile associated with "mississippi" will contain references to "worth" and "reading" and their word frequency in sentence is 1, but the word frequency of mississippi is 3 in entire dictionary. And I want to sort the word frequency of target word in descending order. Anyone can help without importing modules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop over the set of all keys in the input, and then produce the final result:

```
d = [{'mississippi': 1, 'worth': 1, 'reading': 1}, {'commonplace': 1, 'river': 1, 'contrary': 1, 'ways': 1, 'remarkable': 1}, {'considering': 1, 'missouri': 1, 'main': 1, 'branch': 1, 'longest': 1, 'river': 1, 'world--four': 1}, {'seems': 1, 'safe': 1, 'crookedest': 1, 'river': 1, 'part': 1, 'journey': 1, 'uses': 1, 'cover': 1, 'ground': 1, 'crow': 1, 'fly': 1, 'six': 1, 'seventy-five': 1}, {'discharges': 1, 'water': 1, 'st': 1}, {'lawrence': 1, 'twenty-five': 1, 'rhine': 1, 'thirty-eight': 1, 'thames': 1}, {'river': 1, 'vast': 1, 'drainage-basin:': 1, 'draws': 1, 'water': 1, 'supply': 1, 'twenty-eight': 1, 'states': 1, 'territories': 1, 'delaware': 1, 'atlantic': 1, 'seaboard': 1, 'country': 1, 'idaho': 1, 'pacific': 1, 'slope--a': 1, 'spread': 1, 'forty-five': 1, 'degrees': 1, 'longitude': 1}, {'mississippi': 1, 'receives': 1, 'carries': 1, 'gulf': 1, 'water': 1, 'fifty-four': 1, 'subordinate': 1, 'rivers': 1, 'navigable': 1, 'steamboats': 1, 'hundreds': 1, 'flats': 1, 'keels': 1}, {'area': 1, 'drainage-basin': 1, 'combined': 1, 'areas': 1, 'england': 1, 'wales': 1, 'scotland': 1, 'ireland': 1, 'france': 1, 'spain': 1, 'portugal': 1, 'germany': 1, 'austria': 1, 'italy': 1, 'turkey': 1, 'almost': 1, 'wide': 1, 'region': 1, 'fertile': 1, 'mississippi': 1, 'valley': 1, 'proper': 1, 'exceptionally': 1}]
def group(r):
  r = [i for b in r for i in b]
  _d = {}
  for a, b in r:
    if a not in _d:
      _d[a] = b
    else:
      _d[a] += b
  return _d

full_keys = {i for b in map(dict.keys, d) for i in b}
final_results = {(i, sum(i in c for c in d)):group([[(a, b) for a, b in c.items() if a != i] for c in d if i in c]) for i in full_keys}
sorted_results = sorted(final_results.items(), key=lambda x:x[0][-1], reverse=True)
formatted = '\n'.join('{} {}\n'.format(a, b)+'\n'.join('\t{}: {}'.format(c, d) for c, d in i.items()) for (a, b), i in sorted_results)
```

Example output for `'river'`:

```
river 4
   delaware: 1
   remarkable: 1
   supply: 1
   ground: 1
   crow: 1
   pacific: 1
   states: 1
   crookedest: 1
   considering: 1
   draws: 1
   territories: 1
   ways: 1
   six: 1
   seems: 1
   slope--a: 1
   spread: 1
   degrees: 1
   branch: 1
   main: 1
   world--four: 1
   idaho: 1
   commonplace: 1
   seventy-five: 1
   safe: 1
   water: 1
   part: 1
   uses: 1
   longest: 1
   seaboard: 1
   drainage-basin:: 1
   vast: 1
   forty-five: 1
   fly: 1
   country: 1
   cover: 1
   longitude: 1
   twenty-eight: 1
   journey: 1
   contrary: 1
   missouri: 1
   atlantic: 1
```

Comment: Thank you so much Ajax, let me try it now

Comment: Hi Ajax, could you add some explanation in your code? I have some confusion of obtaining full_keys and final_results. Do you have an easier way to get final_results instead of using group function?

Comment: @JimYe There is an easier way, but it requires certain modules :)

Comment: No problem. I will check the code carefully. Could you add some explanation for the full_keys and final_results? Sorry I cannot fully understand the code :(